# Ideas about notification panel

Tags: jquery, html, notifications, local-storage

I am trying to do a notification center in one tab of my website. I want to show notifications from the database and generated directly from the webpage. Should be intercalated, I mean, when arrives, it shows there:

```
13:02 From webpage
12:05 From db
12:01 From db
11:54 From webpage
```

My problem is that I don't know how to implement this. Right now from the db, I am using a JSON response parsed with Jquery and show it in the notification center. But I only retrieve the last row, therefore that query should be stored in somewhere, an array for example and then show the whole array.

Anyone has any idea how to implement this? I'm thinking in using Localstorage from HTML5 or something similar to save the id of each notification. I want to clarify that the notifications generated in the website are stored in nowhere.

Edit:
There are two ways to send notifications:
-From server side stored into db and SELECT from the website using PHP
-From webpage, generated using jquery and displayed direcly into notifications

Comment: Your question is currently too broad. What prevents you from retrieving more than the last item? Do you want to _ask the server in a fixed interval_ or do you want the _server to inform the client_ automatically? Should a client side generated message be stored on the server too or will it only be shown in the notification box?

Comment: The notifications generated by client side only will be shown in the notification box, without storing. But here it's the problem, how can I intercalate both notification sides?. I've updated the question to show where are the notifications. I only select the last message from db selecting the last one and comparing the ID with the previous message shown.